# Django normalize() is showing 1E+1

Tags: django, django-models, decimal, normalize, decimal-point

I'm trying to create a function in my model to display product info, and in my model I have the following:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    @property
    def product_label(self):
    return f'The product price is {self.price.normalize()}'
```

Using normalize() is working fine if the price is something like **10.50**
The output is as the following, which is what I exactly want:

> ```
> The product price is 10.05
> ```

BUT when I have a price like **10.00**, the output displayed shows **1E+1** instead of **10**

> ```
> The product price is 1E+1
> ```

Is there any idea how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

You can fix it this way:

```
@property
def product_label(self):
    return f'The product price is {self.price.normalize():f}'
```

Just by adding `:f` after the method call, to format the `Decimal` object as fixed-point number.

## Explanation

From the documentation:

> **normalize(context=None)**
>
> Normalize the number by stripping the rightmost trailing zeros and converting any result equal to `Decimal('0')` to `Decimal('0e0')`. Used for producing canonical values for attributes of an equivalence class. For example, `Decimal('32.100')` and `Decimal('0.321000e+2')` both normalize to the equivalent value `Decimal('32.1')`.

So, it's not necessarily converting to a human-readable value.

In the FAQ section you can see some solutions provided like this one:

> If an application does not care about tracking significance, it is easy to remove the exponent and trailing zeroes, losing significance, but keeping the value unchanged:
>
> ```
> >>> from decimal import Decimal
> >>> def remove_exponent(d):
> ...     return d.quantize(Decimal(1)) if d == d.to_integral() else d.normalize()
> >>> remove_exponent(Decimal('5E+3'))
> Decimal('5000')
> ```

But in your case, it's enough to format the value.

## Reference

#### Format specifiers

https://peps.python.org/pep-3101/#standard-format-specifiers

#### Decimal FAQ

https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal-faq